# Entity Framework code first one-to-many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'am trying to make a one-to-many relation through `Request` and `Discussion` tables. The fallowing code works fine but I want to make the `Request.ID` property to be foreign key instead of having a extra property like `DiscussionId`. I tried several ways but they all failed.

```
 public class Request
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        // other properties
        public int DiscussionId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Discussion> Discussion { get; set; }
    }

public class Discussion
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need the `DiscussionId`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Ghukas indicates, there's nothing requiring you to have `DiscussionId` as a property on your entity. In fact it's not really doing *anything* there. `Request` has a collection `Discussion`, but this is syntactic sugar, you don't actually even need that property if you don't want to access the discussions directly from your `Request` instance.

What actually creates the relationship is your `Discussion.Request` property. You did not specify an actual property to store the foreign key, but behind the scenes Entity Framework creates one for you, so on your `dbo.Discussions` table, you'll have a column named `Request_ID`, which will be used to hold this relationship. And, it will reference `Request.ID` automatically since that's the primary key of that table.